# How to get topactivity name in android lollipop.?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi need to find out top activity name in android lollipop. 
In my video call recoding application i need to record the skype video call , so here i used top activity methodology, when a particular top activity comes to fore ground, i started the recording, but above Kitkat version like lollipop its problem to get top activity name

i used bellow code. here i used getRunningAppProcesses() in lollipop version but i get only package name. in my project i need to find out top activity name. so please suggest me.

```
private String getTopActivityName() {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (am != null) {
        String topActivityName = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            //For above Kitkat version 
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (tasks.get(0).importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                topActivityName = tasks.get(0).processName;
                System.out.println("topActivityName1 : " + topActivityName);
                return topActivityName;
            }
        } else {
            topActivityName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                    .getClassName();
            System.out.println("topActivityName2 : " + topActivityName);
            return topActivityName;
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: What do you need that for? To tell if your app is in front? There are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: @Ridcully, In my video call recoding application i need to record the skype video call , so here i used top activity methodology, when a particular top activity comes to fore ground, i started the recording, but above Kitkat version like lollipop its problem to get top activity name.

Comment: @challa : are you able to find a solution? i am stuck at similar stage. We need to get a particular top activity name for performing few tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
   List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
   time - 1000 * 1000, time);
   if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
          SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
          for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                  mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),
                  usageStats);
          }
          if (!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
             return Objects.requireNonNull(mySortedMap.get(
                    mySortedMap.lastKey())).getPackageName();
          }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Would you please add an explanation why this code solves the problem? That way your answer will be more helpful for future users and will attract more upvotes.